# Iterator inside f"string

Tags: python

```
array1=[1, 2, 3]
array2=[0, 1, 2]
a = [10, 20, 30]
b = [100, 200, 300]
padded = ['001', '002', '003']

array1 = iter(array1)
array2 = iter(array2)
a = iter(a)
b = iter(b)
padded = iter(padded)


func= (
    f"  array1 {next(array1)}  \n"
    f" array2 {next(array2)}  \n"
    f" ... a {next(a)}  \n"
    f" ... b {next(b)} \n"
    f" padded {next(padded)} \n"
)

for i in range(2):
    print(func)
```

Is not iterating.

Wasn't planning to be learning to code, though here we are. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: *Is not iterating.* is not a good way to tell your problem. Better would be to tell the intended output and the actual output along with errors(if any)

Comment: Why are you using iterators, you can you it in a simple loop ? Is that what you are looking for or you HAVE to use 'iter' and 'next' ?

Comment: @Grall I am too inept to answer this, but I need to 'generate' many unique copies of func.. I'd be interested to see the for loop method :~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*Note that I do not discuss you approach as such. I strictly address your question.*</sub>

---

When you do

```
func = (
    f"  array1 {next(array1)}  \n"
    f" array2 {next(array2)}  \n"
    f" ... a {next(a)}  \n"
    f" ... b {next(b)} \n"
    f" padded {next(padded)} \n"
)
```

... you have defined `func` once for all. It is henceforth just a [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str)ing... for ever...<sup>Incidentally, using `func` to name this string is somehow misleading.</sup>

If you want it to be redefined at each iteration, you have to call your [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)s again and again... A *possible approach[*](https://realpython.com/lessons/zen-of-python/#:%7E:text=There%20should%20be%20one%2D%2D,better%20than%20*right*%20now.)* is to turn your variable `func` into a [callable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callable_object#:%7E:text=A%20callable%20object%2C%20in%20computer,be%20called%20like%20a%20function.), say, using an [anonymous function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression), as follows:

```
func = lambda: (
    f"  array1 {next(array1)}  \n"
    f" array2 {next(array2)}  \n"
    f" ... a {next(a)}  \n"
    f" ... b {next(b)} \n"
    f" padded {next(padded)} \n"
)
```

and then iteratively call it

```
for i in range(2):
    print(func())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate through an f string. Once the variable in the f string is defined it can't be changed after the next iteration. I would recommend using .format instead.

```
func= (
    "  array1 {}  \n".format(next(array1))
    f" array2 {}  \n".format(next(array2))
    f" ... a {}  \n".format(next(a))
    f" ... b {next(b)} \n".format(next(b))
    f" padded {next(padded)} \n".format(next(padded))
)
```

Also don't forget to index the arrays!